# Setting input value to dynamic variable when onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to strip a parameter `listingid` from the URL, and when `onclick` it post a value of an input box as the `listingid`, but i am not able to do so.

Is it possible to do so?

```
function getpic( name )
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );

    if( results == null )
        return null;
    else
        return results[1];
}

var frank_param1 = gup( 'Listingid' );
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="listingid"  onclick="value=list_param">
```

Comment: how do you click on a hidden element?

Comment: in jQuery, at some event you can do `$('input[name="listingid"]').val(getpic( 'Listingid' ))`

Comment: Thats a part of the form, when the form is submitted that is one of the input.

Comment: I'm not sure how `onclick="value=list_param"` is related here. where's the variable `value` declared? And also what is function `gup`?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Jquery for this

```
$('input[name="listingid"]').val(getpic( 'Listingid' ))
```